# Как в Html создать поле для ввода текста и сохранения?

Tags: php, html

Как в Html создать поле для ввода текста и сохранения?

В гугле там одним примеры на php и так далее.
А без php нельзя?

Comment: Ну а где вы хранить хотите ? HTML - только разметка и не более.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма делается раз как средствами html разметки([описание](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)). Но сохранение и последующее получение данных делается только с помощью какой нибудь серверной технологии php или любой другой. Так что на одном html сделать форму, с сохранением данных не возможно.

Comment: А JQuery? не получится?

Comment: Нет. JQuery - это javasctipt  библиотека, она работает в браузере, а сохранение данных происходит на сервере, для сохранения данных нужно использовать серверный язык программирования.